# Какой алгоритм шифрования используется в CryptoStream?

Tags: c#, .net, шифрование

Какой алгоритм шифрования используется в `CryptoStream` в `System.Security.Cryptography` С# .Net?
Хочу написать алгоритм расшифровки на плюсах.